# how to get component given as reference in custom view?

Tags: android, custom-component

Hi I am making a custom view and giving other component id as a reference in it like this

```
<com.example.timerview.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    mtv:associatedTextView="@+id/text_view"
  />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

now I want to use this TextView in CustomView.java so I am doing this in constructor

```
int tId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomView_associatedTextView, 0);
TextView tText = (TextView) findViewById(tId);
```

but I found `tText` is `null` please advise me where I am wrong or How can I do such thing. Please help me.

Comment: what's wrong with `findViewById(R.id.text_view);`?

Comment: its also returns null

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView is not a child of your custom view, which is why `findViewById` cannot find it.

Call `findViewById` from the root view, after the custom view has been attached:

```
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  int tId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomView_associatedTextView, 0);
  TextView tText = (TextView) getRootView().findViewById(tId);
}
```